# How to remove specific section in filename

Tags: filenames, rename

I use my synology DS1515+ and DSM 6.2.2.

I'd like to remove specific section in name of many files.

For example;

abcde(test).mp4 → abcd.mp4

love(1).mp4 → love.mp4

Section that from (  to ) in filename should be removed.

Letters between ( and ) are different in many files.

How can I do this? please help me.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *; do
    echo "Old file: $i"
    new=$(echo "$i" | sed -e 's/\s*(.*)//g')
    echo "New file: $new"
done
```

Old file: abc (csd).mp4
New file: abc.mp4
Old file: def(123).mp4
New file: def.mp4

Just replace echo with mv "$i" "$new".

Comment: Sorry, I missed the first crucial sentence of your post.

Comment: Thankyou for your comment. doesn't it works?